# Query does work on access but not in vb.net no error but ExecuteNonQuery is 0

Tags: visual-studio

I am having a problem with this simple query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE [Recieptnum] = '" & some & "'
```

There is no error but not showing any record, I've checked every thing from connection string to running the query in access directly after I copied the commandtext from vs. any help greatly appreciated the code is

```
Dim some As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim commstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE [Receiptnum] = '" & some & "' "
sqlQuery.CommandText = commstring
'sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some", TextBox1.Text)
Dim b As Integer = sqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Well you're executing a Query with ExecuteNonQuery, which only returns the affected rows, which are probably always 0 in a query and perfectly valid in your case.

Comment: so how do u suggest to see if  there are record in the table with that crateria

Comment: Via a DataReader for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lennart I did it this way

```
sqlQuery.ExecuteReader.FieldCount()
```

which returns column numbers which in my case does not matter as long as there is a hit. Cheers